# Ctrl+Drag in XCode is adding outlets to the wrong file

Tags: xcode, xcode6

I have an OSX project which has a subproject for a helper app.

Ctrl+Dragging to connect an element from the IB to the AppDelegate of the main project doesn't work. It tries to add the outlet to the AppDelegate of the helper app.

So, I Ctrl_Drag a view from IB to the AppDelegate.swift of the main app but the actual connection is made to the helper app's AppDelegate. Not kidding.

Using XCode 6.3.1 with Swift.

Comment: You can't add IBOutlets in your app delegate ._.

Comment: I've added a bunch of outlets to the AppDelegate. Also restarting XCode a number of times fixes the problem for a bit before it resurfaces again.

Comment: Are you developing for OS X? I'm not sure, maybe you're adding VC outlets, I've never seen people do that before.